# Need to remove ugly tumblr left border but having trouble

Tags: html, css, tumblr

The site I'm modifying is: www.fashiontogo.ca

Please view the source code via Google Chrome's ability to view source as I can't provide the HTML or the CSS directly here. It isn't my site, and I didn't develop it from scratch. Look at the profile picture in the top right, or any of the images on the page. You'll see a 1px left border (there is a margin associated with the profile picture, but not the others). That needs to be removed.

The CSS file I've been provided for the site does not contain anything causing this. I've tried removing all instances in the CSS that are either "border" or "border-left" and nothing has changed. The only possible thing that I've been able to do is to remove the surrounding div element for the images (named .img_container). A hack fix (that I'd rather avoid) would be to use jQuery to dynamically remove all the img_container divs at load time, but I'd much rather find some CSS fix to this.

Any suggestions or ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rule

```
.img_container::after { 
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

You have to remove that BG color